# How to write and use C++ method to write/read from any stream?

Tags: c++, stream

I must write class with one method to read data from any stream (cin, ifstream, etc...) and second to write to any stream. I need something like:

```
void save(std::ostream &stream);
```

but no idea how to impement and use it.

Thanks for help.

Comment: What's the question here? What have you tried? What did your research tell you? Where did you get stuck? "I need code that will do this" is not a valid question here on SO

Comment: Remember that `std::cout` is an output stream. If you can write to `std::cout` you can write to any output stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you implement anything, you should determine the structure, layout or protocol to use for storing and loading data members from a file.

Here's a example:

```
struct MyClass
{
  void load_from_stream(std::istream& inp)
  {
    inp >> first_value;
    inp >> second_value;
  }
  unsigned int first_value;
  double second_value;
};
```

The method will accept any object derived from `std::istream`, such as `std::cin` or `std::ifstream`.

Usage:

```
  MyClass  m;
  m.load_from_stream(cin);
```

Similarly, for the `std::ostream` and saving.